# count items in the list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

```
function onSuccess() {
var longest = "";
var listString = "";
var Count = 0;
var listEnumerator = listCollection.getEnumerator();
while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current(),
        title = currentItem.get_title();

    listString += "<br>" + title;

    if (longest.length < title.length)
        longest = title;
    Count = Count + 1;
}
```

need to know how i get the count of items in the longest name of a list. this function help me to find the list who have the longest name but i dont get the count.

Comment: did you try with count++; ? Count +=1;

Comment: Not working :/ I need to connect the count to this list i get when i run the whele loop

Comment: what you need, you want the count the number of longest title? what is the output of the counte( i mean what number it return?

Comment: it returen 1 or 32

Comment: when its the right ansawer is 3

Comment: ok then do it this if (longest.length < title.length){
        longest = title;
    Count = Count + 1;}

Comment: added {} for If statement.

Comment: its working now

Comment: thnxxx for helping

Comment: awesome, i added that in the anwser, so that you can mark it for benifits of community and some repo for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put the if statement in "{}", to get the correct result. replace the part of code with below one.

```
if (longest.length < title.length){
        longest = title;
    Count = Count + 1;}
```